# Array overflowing

Tags: ruby, arrays

Examine the following code:

```
arr = Array.new(3)
for i in 1..5
  arr << i
end
```

This outputs three blank lines, followed by the numbers 1 through 5.

What I'm trying to do is to create an array with a set size that cannot change, that, when pushed to, will fill up from 0-index to the last, and then just overwrite it with any extras, so that the output here will be just the numbers 1, 2 and 5.

How can I do this?

Comment: 1. That code should not output any blank lines. 2. What is "set-size array"? It is not clear. 3. Your question is not clear.

Comment: I edited some. It outputs "nil"'s because that's how Array.new initializes new arrays. Do you have any more editing proposals?

Comment: @EdenLandau IMO you should encapsulate that behavior in a custom class, `Array` just doesn't work this way.

Comment: @EdenLandau No. I don't have any additional fixes except the ones that I wrote above, which are not fixed at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Range#to_a](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Range.html):

```
>> arr = (1..5).to_a
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

**UPDATE**

```
arr = Array.new(3) # => [nil, nil, nil]
(1..5).each_with_index { |x, i|
  arr[[i, arr.size - 1].min] = x
}
arr # => [1, 2, 5]
```

---

**UPDATE2**

```
class FixArray < Array
  def initialize(max_size)
    @idx, @max_size = 0, max_size
    super(max_size)
  end

  def << (v)
    self[@idx] = v
    @idx = [@idx + 1, @max_size - 1].min
    self
  end
end

arr = FixArray.new(3)
(1..5).each do |i|
  arr << i
  p arr
end
```

output

```
[1, nil, nil]
[1, 2, nil]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 5]
```

Comment: That doesn't quite answer my question. I edited for clarity.

Comment: That does do it, but how can it be adjusted to other array sizes?

Comment: @EdenLandau, I updated the code. Hard-coded `2` -> `arr.size - 1`.

Comment: Downvoter: How can I improve the answer?

Comment: @EdenLandau: If this is the preferred answer to your question then the question needs clarification. This no more solves your stated problem than does `arr = [1, 2, 5]`.

Comment: @Borodin, **UPDATE** part solve the problem.

Comment: @falsetru: Yes I understand that, but it works only when copying another array to your fixed-size one, not in general when you are adding items to the array using `<<` which is what your question says.

Comment: @Borodin, I see. I add a code that derived from your code. I did this way because of OP's metion about `an array with a set size that cannot change` and `overwrite`.  Thank you for comment.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I see what you mean.

You need to subclass `Array`. Something like this should do. You may want to write something more elaborate so that the other `Array` methods work properly, like `push`, for instance.

```
class FixArray < Array

  def initialize(max_size)
    @max_size = max_size
    super()
  end

  def << (v)
    if self.size >= @max_size
      self.pop(self.size - @max_size)
      self[-1] = v
    else
      super(v)
    end
    self
  end

end

farr = FixArray.new(3)

(1..5).each do |i|
  farr << i
  p farr
end
```

**output**

```
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 4]
[1, 2, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as this, Ruby Array's expands automatically and when pushing on to it, it always starts from the end of the Array and appends to that.

```
arr = Array.new
```

**Update**

Create a method that does this.

```
def replace_in_array(array, element)
    array.replace([array.take(array.length - 1), element]).flatten
end

>> array = [1,2,3]
>> replace_in_array(array, 12)
>> [1,2,12]
```

This way your array can expand but it will always take the last index and replace it.

Comment: Where do I set the size here?

Comment: Hmm. Is there any way to override this behaviour?

Comment: No, why would you? What you're seeing with the "three empty lines" is that you've defined an array with 3 nil slots and then push the range i onto after the last nil.

Comment: Yes, I figured as much. That's not, of course, the desired outcome. Ho w can I get it to behave exactly like it needs to, though? It's fundamental for my program.

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.new(3)
```

creates an array with three elements set to `nil`. Any data pushed to it will be added *after* the three nils.

If you want your array to be a minimum size then push to it after you have added all the data

```
arr = Array.new
for i in 1..5
  arr << i
end

arr << nil while arr.size < 3
```

this will leave the array set to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. If the loop was `1..2` instead then it would leave it as `[1, 2, nil]`.

If you want something a bit faster for large arrays, use this instead to expand it to the required size

```
arr += Array.new([0, 3 - arr.size].max)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also do something like this :

```
max_size = 3
arr = []
(1..5).each do |x|
  arr.pop if arr.size >= max_size
  arr.push x
end
```

arr  is

`=> [1, 2, 5]`

You don't have to create new classes for this behaviour.